# CryptVerifyMessageSignature returns original message with an additional header, why?

Tags: winapi, signature, pkcs#7, signtool

I have used `signtool` to produce a PKCS#7 bundle that contains:

- a message
- a digital signature
- the signer certificate.

The command that builds this PKCS#7 file is the following:

```
$signtool sign /f signer_certificate.pfx /p ∙∙∙ /fd sha512 /p7 . /p7ce Embedded /p7co 0 my_file
```

This outputs a file named `my_file.p7` in DER form (ASN.1).

Now I wrote a C++ program to verify that, from the bundle, we can extract both the certificate and the message. For this I call [`CryptVerifyMessageSignature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptverifymessagesignature):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<BYTE> InputPkcs7Data;
// read input file into InputPkcs7Data (CreateFile, GetFileSizeEx, ReadFile).
// out of scope.

CRYPT_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA Parameters = {};
Parameters.cbSize = sizeof(Parameters);
Parameters.dwMsgAndCertEncodingType = PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING;
Parameters.hCryptProv = NULL;
Parameters.pfnGetSignerCertificate = NULL;
Parameters.pvGetArg = NULL;

DWORD DecodedMessageLength = 0;
PCCERT_CONTEXT SignerCertificate = NULL;
BOOL Result = CryptVerifyMessageSignature(&Parameters, 0, InputPkcs7Data.data(), InputPkcs7Data.size(), NULL, &DecodedMessageLength, &SignerCertificate);

std::vector<BYTE> DecodedMessage;
DecodedMessage.assign(DecodedMessageLength, 0);

Result = CryptVerifyMessageSignature(&Parameters, 0, InputPkcs7Data.data(), InputPkcs7Data.size(), DecodedMessage.data(), &DecodedMessageLength, &SignerCertificate);

if (Result == FALSE) {
    wprintf(L"Error: %lx\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
    // inspect Memory
    CertFreeCertificateContext(SignerCertificate);
}
```

My problem here is that, even if `CryptVerifyMessageSignature` succeeds, What I get into `DecodedMessage` is not the original message. There are always several leading bytes that seem like garbage at first, but that contain information about the message length. I managed to understand that `DecodedMessage` is sequenced as follows, depending on the length of original message:

- OriginalMessageLength ⩽ 127 bytes:

  - 0x04
  - a byte representing the length of the message
  - the message
- 128 bytes ⩽ OriginalMessageLength ⩽ 255 bytes:

  - 0x04
  - 0x81
  - a byte representing the length of the message
  - the message
- 256 bytes ⩽ OriginalMessageLength ⩽ 65535 bytes:

  - 0x04
  - 0x82
  - two bytes representing, in Big Endian, the length of the message
  - the message
- 65536 bytes ⩽ OriginalMessageLength ⩽ 16777215 bytes:

  - 0x04
  - 0x83
  - three bytes representing, in Big Endian, the length of the message
  - the message
- OriginalMessageLength ⩾ 16777216 bytes:

  - 0x04
  - 0x84
  - four bytes representing, in Big Endian, the length of the message
  - the message.
    (I did not try with messages larger than 4GiB).

This is really unexpected to me. Where does this “header information” stem from, and is there a way I can avoid getting it when calling CryptVerifyCertificate?

Is it possible that `signtool` is not the right tool for generating the signed message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the decoded message is an `OCTET STRING` encoded using Distinguished Encoding Rules as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding. 04 is the tag number for OCTET STRING.